# Interpret whatfuck

Tags: code-golf, interpreter

Smallfuck is a brainfuck-like language with 1-bit cells.  It has the following instructions:

```
> Increment the pointer
< Decrement the pointer
* Flip the current bit
[ If the current bit is not set, jump to the instruction after the matching ]
] If the current bit is set, jump to the instruction after the matching [ 
    ( or just jump unconditionally to matching [ )
```

Whatfuck adds one more instruction:

```
? Nondeterministically set the current bit to 0 or 1.
```

A whatfuck program does not take any input.  It can result in one of 3 possibilities: `1` (accept), `0` (reject) or it may never halt.

The program will result in `1` if there exists a sequence of bits chosen for `?`s which results in the program terminating with `1` as the current bit.

The program terminates with `0` if all possible choices terminate with current bit `0`,

If some choices don't terminate, and all choices which terminate do so with `0`, then the program will never terminate.

Your interpreter should run all possibilities simultaneously.  You can't try `0` first and then try `1`, because some programs will not terminate when they should.  For example, `*[?*]*` will accept with the choice `1`, but never terminate if you always choose `0`.

[As an example, here is a python 2 interpreter I wrote, not golfed](http://pastebin.com/Hp85cg1R)

### Rules

- Your interpreter must accept a whatfuck program from stdin and print its result.
- You may assume the whatfuck program only contains characters `[]<>*?`
- The array of bits is unbounded on both ends.
- Shortest code wins.

### Some Test Cases

This will fail if your code always tries `0` first

```
*[?*]*
1
```

Is there a subset of `{-7,-3, 5, 8}` whose sum is 3?

```
*<<<<<?[<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]?[<<<<<<]?[>>>>>>>>>>]?[>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]<
1
```

Is there a subset of `{-7,-3, 5, 8}` whose sum is 4?

```
*<<<<<<<?[<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]?[<<<<<<]?[>>>>>>>>>>]?[>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]<
0
```

Is there a way to assign boolean values to `a`,`b` and `c` such that

`(a XOR b) AND (a XOR c) AND (b XOR c)` is true?

```
?[*>*>*<<]?[*>*>>*<<<]?[*>>*>*<<<]>[*>[*>[*>*<]<]<]>>>
0
```

Answer (score 5):

### Python, 305 chars

```
P=raw_input()+'$'
S=[(0,0,[])]
F={}
R={}
i=r=0
for c in P:
 if'['==c:S+=i,
 if']'==c:j=S.pop();F[j]=R[i]=i-j
 i+=1
while S*(1-r):p,t,B=S.pop(0);c=P[p];b=B.count(t)%2;p+=1+F.get(p,0)*(1-b)-R.get(p,0)*b;t+=(c=='>')-(c=='<');B=B+[t]*(c=='*');r|=(c=='$')&b;S+=[(p,t,B)]*(c!='$')+[(p,t,B+[t])]*(c=='?')
print r
```

Keeps track of the nondeterministic set of states in `S`, each with a code position `p`,  a tape position `t`, and a list of tape indexes `B`.  A tape index can appear multiple times in the list `B`, the tape at that index is 1 if the index appears an odd number of times in `B`.

Comment: Save 1 byte by replacing `t+=(c=='>')-(c=='<');` with `t+=c=='>';t-=c=='<';`, another by replacing `B=B+[t]*(c=='*')` with `B+=[t]*(c=='*')`, and a third by replacing `p+=1+F.get(p,0)*(1-b)-R.get(p,0)*b;` with `p+=1+F.get(p,0)*-~-b-R.get(p,0)*b;`. Great answer! (Sorry, I know this answer's super old!)

Answer (score 5):

Infinite tape ahoy!

### Haskell, 516

```
i((p:l,r),(π,'<':φ))=[((l,p:r),('<':π,φ))]
i((l,p:r),(π,'>':φ))=[((p:l,r),('>':π,φ))]
i((l,p:r),(π,'*':φ))=[((l,1-p:r),('*':π,φ))]
i((l,_:r),(π,'?':φ))=[((l,b:r),('?':π,φ))|b<-[0,1]]
i(s@(l,0:r),(π,'[':φ))=[(s,m(']':π,φ)0)]
i(s,(π,'[':φ))=[(s,(']':π,φ))]
i(s,(π,']':φ))=[(s,ξ$m(']':φ,π)0)]
i _=[]
m(l,']':r)0=('[':l,r)
m(l,']':r)n=m('[':l,r)$n-1
m(l,'[':r)n=m(']':l,r)$n+1
m(l,c:r)n=m(c:l,r)n
ν=null;ο=0:ο
μ[]="0"
μ ω|ν[ψ|ψ@((_,b:_),_)<-ω,b>0,ν$i ψ]=μ$ω>>=i
μ _="1"
ξ(a,b)=(b,a)
main=interact$ \ζ->μ[((ο,ο),("",ζ))]
```

Comment: It's remarkable how often Haskell answers succeed in getting top votes even if there are other answers with objectively better score around...

Comment: μ              :)            ..............

Answer (score 1):

### Python (<s>405</s> <s>399</s> 379)

It takes the input on one line, but I "may assume the whatfuck program only contains characters `[]<>*?`" and newline isn't on that list :P

```
w,i,p,a={},0,raw_input(),[(0,0,[],[])]
for c in p:
 if c=='[':a+=i,
 if c==']':g=a.pop();w[i],w[g]=g,i
 i+=1
i,z=0,lambda l:l and l.pop()or 0
while a:
 n,c,l,r=a.pop(0)
 try:o=p[n]
 except:
        if c:i=1;break
        continue
 if o=='*':c=not c
 if o=='>':l+=c,;c=z(r)
 if o=='<':r+=c,;c=z(l)
 if o in'[]'and(']'==o)==c:n=w[n]
 if o=='?':a+=(n+1,not c,l[:],r[:]),
 a+=(n+1,c,l,r),
print i
```

Comment: `.append(item)` -> `+=[item]`, remove `k` and replace all calls with `a+=[...]` to save a few characters.

Comment: @beary605: thanks, however I ended up using `+=item,` which is even shorter.